# How to detect .NET WPF memory leak or GC long run?

Tags: .net, wpf, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have the next very strange situation and problem:

- .NET 4.0 application for diagram editing (WPF).
- Runs ok in my PC: 8GB RAM, 3.0GHz, i7 quad-core.
- While creating objects (mostly diagram nodes and connectors, plus all the undo/redo information) the TaskManager show, as expected, some memory usage "jumps" (up and down).
- These mem-usage "jumps" also remains executing AFTER user interaction ended. Maybe this is the GC cleaning/regorganizing memory?
- To see what is going on, I've used the Ants mem profiler, but somewhat it prevents those "jumps" to happen after user interaction.

PROBLEM: It Freezes/Hangs after seconds or minutes of usage in some slow/weak laptos/netbooks of my beta testers (under 2GHz of speed and under 2GB of RAM). I was thinking of a memory leak, but...

EDIT 1: Also, there is the case that the memory usage grows and grows until collapse (only in slow machines).

- In a Windows XP Mode machine (VM in Win 7) with only 512MB of RAM Assigned it works fine without mem-usage "jumps" after user interaction (no GC cleaning?!).

EDIT 2: The problem is worse when the system has some other heavy programs running (like Visual Studio, Office and Web pages open). Not even the first symbol of diagram can be created while the memory usage takes off like a rocket to space (hundreds of MBs consumed in seconds). Anyone with similar experiences? what were they strategies?

So, I really have a big trouble because I cannot reproduce the error, only see these strange behaviour (mem jumps), and the tool supposed to show me what is happening is hiding the problem (like the "observer's paradox").

Any ideas on what's happening and how to solve it?

EDIT 3: This screenshot of the Ants memory profiler shows that the huge consumption of ram (in crescendo) if from unmanaged resources.

[image]

But, what can be consuming so much memory, so fast??!!!

Comment: After adding a GC.Collect() call after every command execution (those which create nodes and connectors in the diagram, plus the undo/redo info) the result is almost the same in the slow PC.

Comment: This question is Answered. But the problem remains UNSOLVED. In the assumption that the unmanaged code causing the problem is found, what would I do? contact the manufacturer of the native component or library to report them a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would suggest that you're likely creating a lot of "garbage" - basically, creating and letting many objects go out of scope quickly, but which take long enough to get into Gen1 or Gen2.  This puts a large burden on the GC, which in turn can cause freezes and hangs on many systems.

> To see what is going on, I've used the Ants mem profiler, but somewhat it prevents those "jumps" to happen after user interaction.

The reason this profiler (ANTS), specifically, could mask this behavior is that it forces a full GC every time you take a memory snapshot.  This would make it look like there is no memory "leak" (as there isn't), but does not show the total memory pressure on the system.

A tool like [PerfView](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2011/12/28/publication-of-the-perfview-performance-analysis-tool.aspx) could be used to investigate the GC's behavior during the runtime of the process.  This would help you track the number of GCs that occur, and your application state at that point in time.

Comment: I see...  I'm gonna learn more and improve GC as far as possible. And of course I will use the PerfView tool to see what else I can discover. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

What you describe is all entirely normal behavior for a .NET program, there is no indication that there's anything wrong with your code.

By far the biggest issue is that TaskMgr.exe is just not a very good program to tell you what's happening in your process.  It displays the "working set" for a process, a number that has very little to do with the amount of memory the process uses.

Working set is the amount of RAM that your process uses.  Every process gets 2 gigabytes of *virtual* memory to use for code and data.  Even on your virtual XP box with only 512 MB of RAM.   All of those processes however have only a set amount of RAM to work with.  On a lowly machine that can be as little as a gigabyte.

Clearly having multiple processes running, each with gigabytes of virtual memory with only a gigabyte of *real* memory takes some magic.  That's provided by the operating system, Windows virtualizes the RAM.  In other words, it creates the illusion for each process that it is running by its own on a machine with 2 gigabytes of RAM.  This is done by a feature called *paging*, whenever a process needs to read or write memory, the operating system grabs a chunk of RAM to provide the physical memory.

Inevitably, it has to take *away* some RAM from another process so that it can be made available to yours.  Whatever was previously in that chunk of RAM needs to be preserved.  That's what the *paging file* does, it stores the content of RAM that was paged out.

Clearly this does not come for free, disks are pretty slow and paging is an expensive operation.  That's why lowly machines perform poorly when you ask them to run several large programs.  The real measure for this is also visible in TaskMgr.exe but you have to add it.  View + Select Columns and tick "Page fault delta".  Observe this number while your process runs.  When you see it spike, you can expect your program to slow down a great deal and the displayed memory usage to change rapidly.

Addressing your observations:

> creating objects ... the TaskManager show, as expected, some memory usage "jumps"

Yes, you are using RAM so the working set goes up.

> These mem-usage "jumps" also remains executing AFTER user interaction ended

No slam dunk, but other processes get more time to execute, using RAM in turn and bumping some of yours out.  Check the Page fault delta column.

> I've used the Ants mem profiler, but somewhat it prevents those "jumps" to happen after user interaction.

Yes, memory profilers focus on real memory usage of your program, the virtual memory kind.  They largely ignore working set, there isn't anything you can do about it and the number is meaningless because it really depends on what *other* processes are running.

> there is the case that the memory usage grows and grows until collapse

That can be a side-effect of the garbage collector but that isn't typical.  You are probably just seeing Windows trimming your working set, chucking out pages so you don't consume too many.

> In a Windows XP Mode machine (VM in Win 7) with only 512MB of RAM Assigned it works fine

That's likely because you haven't installed any large programs on that WM that would compete for RAM.  XP was also designed to work well on machines with very little memory, it is smooth on a machine with 256 MB.  That's most definitely not the case for Vista/Win7, they were designed to take advantage of modern machine hardware.  A feature like Aero is nice eye candy but *very* expensive.

> The problem is worse when the system has some other heavy programs running

Yes, you are competing with those other processes needing lots of RAM.

> Not even the first symbol of diagram can be created while the memory usage takes off like a rocket

Yes, you are seeing pages getting mapped back to RAM, getting reloaded from the paging file and the ngen-ed .ni.dll files.  Rapidly increasing your working set again.  You'll also see the Page fault delta number peaking.

So concluding, your WPF program just consumes a lot of memory and needs the horse power to operate well.  That's not easy to fix, it takes a pretty drastic redesign to lower the resource requirements.  So just put the system requirements on the box, it is entirely normal to do so.

Comment: I don't agree with your conclussion. My application does not consumes so much memory, is something else... GC?, GD+?, or other unmanaged element, as shown by the mem profiler, and occurs in some nebulous circumstances.

Comment: All the evidence you presented does in fact show that your app uses a lot of virtual memory.  It is quite visible in the profiler screen shot, 700 megabytes is a good sized chunk.  It is entirely unclear to me what evidence you used to insist that it doesn't.  Profilers are not very good at breaking down unmanaged memory usage.  Because it is, well, unmanaged.  It is commonly used for things like bitmaps, BitmapSource is a very small managed class but wraps a big chunk of unmanaged data.  The bitmap pixels.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that still cannot see anything wrong in my code (which is managed). Considering that the leak is in the unmanaged memory, the program loads just some graphics (splash screen, plus button icons) and I have no background tasks working, I can only deduce that there is an out-of-my-control component which has the leak.

Comment: First sentence of my answer.  Again, there is no indication that there's anything wrong with your program.  It is only a leak if you can consistently get your program to crash with an OutOfMemoryException.  There's another kind of programming where you *do* get to explicitly manage any unmanaged resources.  You chose to program with WPF however, a world away from C++.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know exactly what's going on without seeing your code, but here are a few suggestions:

First, some information about the Garbage Collector. The most important thing to know is that the GC is non-deterministic, you can't know when it will run. Even calling GC.Collect() is only a suggestion, not a command. The Gen0 heap is for locally scoped objects and is collected frequently. If an object survives Gen0 collection it will be moved to the Gen1 heap. After a bit the Gen1 heap will be collected and if an object survives collection it is moved to the Gen2 heap which is less frequently collected. For this reason it is possible to see a saw-tooth pattern in a memory graph if you are allocating a lot of objects that make it into the Gen1 or Gen2 heap.

Using a tool like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) examine the size of the managed heaps (Gen0, Gen1, Gen2 and the large object heap) and find out where the memory is being held. If you've got lots of short lived objects (Gen1 heap) think of a way to reuse memory instead of re-allocating - something like an [object pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) works well for that.

Also, try comparing the total size of the managed heaps against total private bytes of your application. Private bytes includes both managed and unmanaged memory allocated by your application. If there is a big difference between the size of the managed heaps and the private bytes it's likely that your application is allocating unmanaged objects (via graphic objects, streams, etc) that aren't getting disposed correctly. Look for objects that implement IDisposable, but don't have Dispose() getting called.

Another problem could be heap fragmentation. If you're application is allocating large objects which it can't fit into the current heap it will request more memory from the OS. A solution to avoid this is to allocate smaller chunks or memory or to allocate them in sequential blocks rather than randomly (think array vs linked list). A tool like the ANTS Memory profiler should be able to tell you that this is taking place.

@ReedCopsey recommendation of PerfView (or it's predecessor the CLR Profiler) is a good one and will give you a better idea how your memory is being allocated.